# How can I limit the allowed screen sizes (e.g. to tablet only) in a trigger.io forge project using crosswalk?

Tags: android, trigger.io

There does not appear to be a configuration setting to limit allowed screens for Play Store distribution for android builds, as there is in the iOS configuration.

Normally, I would accomplish this by editing the `AndroidManifest.xml` if this were a native application, like so:

```
<manifest ... >
    <supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"
                      android:normalScreens="false"
                      android:largeScreens="true"
                      android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
    ...
</manifest>
```

I looked into creating a post-build hook that would edit that file and then run before `forge package`, but by the time the forge toolkit has returned the build, the manifest file is already in `axml` format.

This application is using the crosswalk build mode, but from what I can tell it reads platform-specific configuration from android as well, but adds the crosswalk framework in the process.

(Note: While it would be nice to allow all screen sizes for this application, it is not currently possible for devices smaller than a tablet to have a usable experience).

Any direction on how to do this with a trigger.io config or how to use a pre/post-build script would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want this?  The definition of what is a tablet vs a phone is pretty fluid-  I have phones bigger than some low end tablets.  The only real difference is if it comes with a cellular radio or not.  WHy needlessly limit your reach this way?

Comment: I would be fine, even would prefer limiting to a certain screen size -- you're certainly correct that there are big phones and small tablets -- but below about 6" (and even that's pushing it) this application is simply not usable.  It's my understanding that this is what these specific manifest options do, though I am certainly open to being shown otherwise.